# How to use variable name in a switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Can I somehow simplify my code below and use only one switch statement? It looks like I need 3rd switch so it would be great to use only one if possible.

```
    $input_separator= $_REQUEST['input_separator'];

    switch ($input_separator) {  
        case "new_line":
            $input_separator="\n";
            break;
        case "comma":
            $input_separator=",";
            break;
        case "none":
            $input_separator="";
            break;
    }



    $output_separator= $_REQUEST['output_separator'];

    switch ($output_separator) {
        case "new_line":
            $output_separator="\n";
            break;
        case "comma":
            $output_separator=",";
            break;
        case "none":
            $output_separator="";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: a switch() is used to compare a SINGLE value against a list of potential matching values. it is just a nicer way of doing `if() else if() else if() else if()`. If you want to compare TWO values, you can, but it gets VERY ugly and subject to many hard-to-diagnose bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like you need *any* `switch` statements:

```
$input_separator = $_REQUEST['input_separator'] == "new_line" ? "\n" : "";
$output_separator = $_REQUEST['output_separator'] == "new_line" ? "\n" : "";
```

EDIT: Try this:

```
$separators = Array(
    "new_line"=>"\n",
    "comma"=>",",
    "none"=>""
);
$input_separator = $separators[$_REQUEST['input_separator']];
$output_separator = $separators[$_REQUEST['output_separator']];
```

Comment: Great answer, why didn't I think about that?

Comment: Don't worry, it took me a while to figure out I could do that :p Real space-saver!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use simple function?

```
function convert_seperator($seperator){
    $ret = '';
    switch ($seperator) {  
        case "new_line":
            $ret = "\n"; // or $ret = PHP_EOL;
            break;
        case "comma":
            $ret = ",";
            break;
        case "none":
            $ret = "";
            break;
        default:
            exit('Invalid seperator');
    }
    return $ret;
}
$input_separator = convert_seperator($_REQUEST['input_separator']);
$output_separator = convert_seperator($_REQUEST['output_separator']);
```